# Find shared numbers between two bins

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm struggling to come up with a mathematical formulae to do this. Let's say there are numbers starting with 0 which are distributed sequentially into 2 sets of bins.

First set of bins has 3 bins (Let's call it X).

```
0th: 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 
1st: 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
2nd: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17
```

Similarly the second set of bins has 5 bins (Let's call Y)

```
0th: 0, 5, 10, 15
1st: 1, 6, 11, 16
2nd: 2, 7, 12, 17
3rd: 3, 8, 13, 18
4th: 4, 9, 14, 19
```

Is there a formulae to calculate what numbers will be shared between ath bin from first set (where a < X) and bth bin from second set (b < Y)?

For e.g. 0th bin from first set and 2nd bin from second set has numbers 12, 27.... Similarly 0th bin from first set and 0th bin from second set has 0, 15...

Comment: I would consider residue classes modulo 3 and 5 and the so-called Chinese Remainder Theorem.  In particular the numbers in the intersection you describe will be a residue class modulo 15.  So you are asking for a formula to determine which residue class that is.

Comment: Residue class.. that's a new term for me. Need to look up.